# Intent chooser not showing all available options (samsung phones) - Share content

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile

This is the code for the intent:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,resources.getString(R.string.app_name));
startActivity(openInChooser);
```

In Samsung phones the chooser only shows the native email apps but not the ones that have been installed from the play store. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Are you sure that the email apps that you installed support this particular `Intent` structure?

Comment: Yes, one of the apps I installed is Outlook. In other phones (Nexus, Oneplus) the chooser shows the option but not in a Samsung phone

Comment: You might try calling `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`, with this `Intent`, and see if Outlook shows up as a candidate activity. If it does, then Samsung screwed with the system chooser.

Comment: Yes, the outlook app is shown in the result.

Comment: :: shrug :: You could try removing `createChooser()`, and just invoking `emailIntent` directly, to see if it is the manually-requested chooser that somehow is the problem. But otherwise I don't know how you would get Samsung to stop filtering Outlook out of the chooser.

Comment: By invoking `emailIntent` directly the default email app is launched, no chooser to select another app :(